# How do I stop unwanted information from being listed on the lock screen?

Tags: lock-screens

No - This is not about "sensitive information".

I just upgraded to Lollipop and my lock screen display was changed by the upgrade.

On the lock screen I now see notifications for

- text messages; this is good
- emails; this is good
- application updates and system notifications; this is bad and needs to go away

I've looked in the Notifications settings and tested the "while locked" settings but this does not achieve what I want.

How do I stop unwanted information like "3 updates available" from appearing on the lock screen?

Comment: When you long-press on such notification you would see an icon with `!`. Tap it and you would see something like "Show on lockscreen". Disable it for that app (Play Store here). Which Android version and device is it?

Comment: Thank you, Firelord. Is there a system-level equivalent to doing that? It's a Samsung S4, Lollipop 5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want them at all you can go to `settings > sound & notification > app notifications` then turn of the notifications you don't want. That would be the best way I know and use.

Comment: Hi programming - Thanks, but that's a one-at-a-time approach. I was hoping for something a little less cruel and unusual...

Comment: You can help the problem by going to the apps that you want to see and give them priority.